# How do I move files to specific directories based on a pattern in the filename?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

If any of this isn't particularly clear, please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify.

I basically need to sort a set of files with various extensions and similar patterns to the filename, into directories and subdirectories that match the pattern and type of extension.

To elaborate a bit:

1. All files, regardless of extension, begin with the pattern "zz####" where #### is a number from 1 to 900; "zz1.zip through zz950.zip, zz1.mov through zz950.mov, zz1.mp4 through zz950.mp4"
2. Some files contain additional characters; "zz360_hello_world.zip"
3. Some files contain spaces; "zz370_hello world.zip"
4. I need these files to be sorted and moved into directories and subdirectories following a particular format: "/home/hello/zz1/zip, /home/hello/zz1/vid"
5. If the directories and/or subdirectories don't exist, I need them created.

Example:

```
zz400_testing.zip       ----> /home/hello/zz400/zip
zz400 testing video.mov ----> /home/hello/zz400/vid

zz500.zip                       ----> /home/hello/zz500/zip
zz500_testing another video.mp4 ----> /home/hello/zz500/vid
```

I found a few answers around here for simpler use-cases, but wasn't able to get anything working for my particular needs.

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT: Adding the code I've been messing with

```
for f in *.zip; do
    set=`echo "$f"|sed 's/[0-9].*//'`
    dir="/home/demo/$set/photos"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

I think I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around how to match with regex. I've got this far with it:

```
[demo@alpha grep]$ echo zz433.zip|sed 's/[0-9].*//'
zz
```

The script will run the mkdir, and even move the zip files into their proper place. I just can't get it to create the proper top-level directory (zz433).

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?  `mkdir` creates directories, `ls` with wildcards selects the files, or `find` can do that as well, `mv` moves files, if you need to loop on the files, use `while`, not `for` since `for` will not handle spaces correctly.  Try it out, if you have issues post here we will help you move forward.

Comment: @Nic3500 My apologies, I've edited my post with the relevant information. I'm new to this >_<

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` command here doesn't do what you're trying to achieve:

> ```
> set=`echo "$f"|sed 's/[0-9].*//'`
> ```

The meaning of the regular expression `[0-9].*` is "a digit followed by anything".
The `s///` command of `sed` performs a replacement.
The result is effectively removing everything from the input starting from the first digit.
So for "zz360_hello_world.zip" it removes everything starting from "3",
leaving only "zz".

Note also that to match the files, the pattern `*.zip` doesn't match your description. You're looking for files starting with "zz" and a number from 1 up to 900. If you don't mind including numbers > 900 then you can write the loop expression like this:

```
for f in zz[0-9][^0-9]* zz[0-9][0-9][^0-9]* zz[0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]*; do
```

Or the same thing more compactly:

```
for f in zz{[0-9],[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]}[^0-9]*; do
```

These are glob patterns.
`zz[0-9][^0-9]*` means "start with 'zz', followed by a digit, followed by a non-digit, followed by anything".
In the above example I use three patterns to cover the cases of "zz" followed by 1, 2 or 3 digits, followed by a non-digit.
The second example is a more compact form of the first,
the idea is that `a{b,c}d` expands to `abd` and `acd`.

Next, to get the appropriate prefix, you could use pattern matching with a `case` statement and extract substrings.
The syntax of these patterns is the same glob syntax as in the previous example in the `for` statement.

```
case "$f" in
    zz[0-9][0-9][0-9]*) prefix=${f:0:5} ;;
    zz[0-9][0-9]*) prefix=${f:0:4} ;;
    zz[0-9]*) prefix=${f:0:3} ;;
esac
```

It seems you also want to create grouping by file type. You could get the file extension by chopping off the beginning of the name until the dot with `ext=${f##*.}`, and then use a `case` statement as in the earlier example to map extensions to the desired directory names.

Putting the above together:

```
for f in zz{[0-9],[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]}[^0-9]*; do
    case "$f" in
        zz[0-9][0-9][0-9]*) prefix=${f:0:5} ;;
        zz[0-9][0-9]*) prefix=${f:0:4} ;;
        zz[0-9]*) prefix=${f:0:3} ;;
    esac

    ext=${f##*.}
    case "$ext" in
        mov|mp4) group=vid ;;
        *) group=$ext ;;
    esac

    dir="/home/demo/$prefix/$group"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered part of my own question!

```
for f in *.zip; do
    set=`echo "$f"|grep -o -P 'zz[0-9]+.{0,0}'`
    dir="/home/demo/$set/photos"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

Basically, the following script will grab files like:

```
zz232.zip
zz233test.zip
zz234 test.zip
```

Then it will create the top-level directory (zz####), the photos sub-directory, and move the file into place:

```
/home/demo/zz232/photos/zz232.zip
/home/demo/zz233/photos/zz233test.zip
/home/demo/zz234/photos/zz234 test.zip
```

Moving on to expanding the script for additional functionality.

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you see my answer? It solves more than just the broken `sed` and regex in the question, and more efficiently then this answer.

Comment: @janos I did, and I appreciate it! To be honest though, I'm a total noob here, and your answer wen't completely over my head.

Comment: I added more explanation to my answer. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

for file in *; do
    if [[ $file =~ ^(zz[0-9]+).*\.(zip|mov|mp4)$ ]]; then
        ext=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        if [ $ext = "mov" -o $ext = "mp4" ]; then
            ext="vid"
        fi
        dir="/home/hello/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/$ext"
        mkdir -p $dir
        mv "$file" $dir
    fi
done
```

Hope this helps.